# Around Hiram's barn

Tags: expressions, phrase-origin, is-it-a-phrase

For most of my life I have used an expression "go around Hiram's barn" to mean an unnecessarily complicated way to do something or an unnecessarily circuitous route.

Recently my daughter informed me that the real expression is "around Robin Hood's barn", and that "around Hiram's barn" is an expression that is unique to me alone.  While I will admit to sometimes making up such phrases, it seems to me that this is one that I originally heard elsewhere, perhaps from my father.  I am curious: Has anyone else has ever heard the expression "go around Hiram's barn"?

I am 69 years old and grew up in Ohio. My parents and grandparents were from New York City (one grandmother was originally from England, and had some rural and some urban background).

Comment: Hello, Jeff. Questions on ELU are best when accompanied by reasonable research. Have you found anything on the internet? If your daughter is right, this isn't a topic for ELU, which looks at standard usages.

Comment: A search on Google.books shows no hits for the expression, so possibly this is a part of [_familect_.](https://allthingslinguistic.com/post/58186019838/speaking-it-in-the-family) i.e. a family dialect. Quite possibly in the history of your family there was an _actual_ Hiram and his barn.

Comment: Thank you to Edwin and Cascabel for replying.  I did search Google and Bing but found no references to the expression.  In answer to Cascabel's questions, I am 69 years old and grew up in Ohio.  My parents and grandparents were from New York City (one grandmother was originally from England, and had some rural and some urban background).  I had not previously heard of familects, but that could very well be what this is.

Comment: Cascabel, thank you for your further input.

Comment: Actually..there are a number of people here who like this type of question. Nailing down an expression and its origin can be a lot of fun. I am quite sure that at this very moment there are several users looking up the expression. I also researched it, but alas, it seems your daughter is probably correct. Good luck. It can be a disconcerting  moment in one's life when suddenly it is discovered that something you believed all your life is possibly not quite right.

Comment: Something dating to the Tulsa Amusement park and a conflation of the ticket office called Hiram’s barn, with the adjacent ‘scenic railway’? http://www.batesline.com/archives/2018/03/crystal-city-amusement-park.html

Comment: Spagirl:  That is very interesting information about Hiram's Barn which was in an amusement park in Tulsa that was in existence until 1956 (I googled it).  This is relevant because my family lived in Oklahoma City from 1950 to 1952, so it may have been an Oklahoma expression (or some variant on one) around that time.

Comment: Cascabel: You are right that this is very interesting.  Even though it's not exactly what I believed it is fascinating to me

Comment: From Thad Stem, [_Ransacking Words and Customs, from A to Izzard_](https://books.google.com/books?id=FB4y1QNGKxYC&q=%22around+Robin+Hood%27s+barn%22&dq=%22around+Robin+Hood%27s+barn%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj94dyYoNHjAhUYFTQIHWnQAJc4FBDoAQhKMAY) (1977): "'Robin Hood's barn' means the vast outdoors, from the legend that the famous British outlaw, hero of ballads, stabled his horses under the canopy of the sky. (In common parlance, '**To go around Robin Hood's barn**' has ancient continued use to mean the attainment of the desired result by devious or circuitous methods. ...

Comment: ... When a student arrived at the right answer, or conclusion, after desultory wanderings, his teacher often said the student had been 'around Robin Hood's barn.' 'Robin Hood In Barnsdale stood' is the only extant line, or phrase, from a song once said to be immensely popular. British jurists, and a few American judges, used to admonish attorneys who spoke irrelevantly, 'Robin Hood in Barnsdale stood,' and the phrase has limited pertinence in common American parlance to denote vacuity."

Comment: Yep, the Hiram's Barn in Tulsa would be quite appropriate.  It's notable in shape (a tall tower) and size and, especially in a crowd, it would be a fairly long hike around it.

Comment: Were your father or grandfathers Freemasons? Rarely, but on occasion, we refer to something as Hiram's something. If the lodge has a barn, it might be called Hiram's barn by members of that lodge.

Answer (score 6):

It may or may not be relevant to the expression that you ask about, but Frederick Cassidy & Joan Hall, *Dictionary of Regional English*, volume 2 (1991) has this entry for the word *Hiram*:

> **Hiram** *n* ... Sense[:] A rustic—also used as a contemptuous term of address. [Cited occurrences:] **1939** [Godfrey] Irwin *Amer[ican] Tramp and Underworld Slang]* 99, *Hiram*.—Many of the old time yeggs [=tramp thieves] preyed upon the country post offices in the districts populated by farmers or, traditionally, "Hirams." **1932** Faulkner, *Light in August* 172 M[ississippi], You better go back to the farm, Hiram. **1942** [Lester] Berrey [& Melvin] Van den Bark *Amer[ican] Thesaurus of] Slang* 391.3, *Rustic; Bumpkin...* Hiram.

Evidently, in at least some parts of the U.S. during at least some part of the twentieth century, "Hiram" was a generic quasi-name assigned to a farmer, conveying the sense "country bumpkin." That being the case, "Hiram's barn" might be a hypothetical barn in a remote rural area—and "going around Hiram's barn" might imply going far out of one's way to get somewhere instead of taking a more direct and logical route.

I don't know whether this rustic sense of *Hiram* is central to the expression "go around Hiram's barn"—but it might be. And if anyone could be expected to own a barn way out in the middle of nowhere, it would be Hiram.

Answer (score 4):

As a British English speaker, and having grown up near [Sherwood Forest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherwood_Forest), where, legend has it, Robin Hood lived with his "Merry Men", I have never heard the phrase: it seems to be American.

https://wordhistories.net/2018/12/05/robin-hoods-barn/ gives:

> *"The earliest known use of Robin Hood’s barn is from a letter written in 1797 by the American book agent and author Mason Locke Weems (1759-1825)—I could not determine whether he used the phrase literally or figuratively, as I could not consult the letter:*

```
[as quoted in the Oxford English Dictionary (3rd edition, 2010)]
```

> 1797   M. L. Weems in P. L. Ford Mason Locke Weems (1929) II. 77 *I can sell them abundantly fast without the trouble of going round Robin Hood’s barn.*

Phrases.org has this credible explanation at https://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/5/messages/1405.html

> ALL AROUND ROBIN HOOD'S BARN - "Robin Hood (or 'Robert of the wood,' as some have explained the name) may have been altogether a legendary figure or may have actually existed. No one knows. The earliest literary reference to him is in Langland's 'Piers Plowman,' written about 1377. He may have lived, according to some light evidence, toward the latter part of the twelfth century. But Robin Hood's house was Sherwood Forest; its roof the leaves and branches. His dinner was the king's deer; his wealth the purses of hapless travelers. What need had he of a barn, and how was it laid out if to go around it means, as the use of the phrase implies, a rambling roundabout course? The explanation is simple. He had no barn. His granary, when he had need of one, was the cornfields of the neighborhood. To go around his barn was to make a circuitous route around the neighborhood fields." From "A Hog on Ice" (1948, Harper & Row) by Charles Earle Funk. This is one in a series of four books by Mr. Funk now available in one volume.

(My reading of this is that Sherwood Forest itself was "Robin Hood's Barn" as it was where everything that Robin Hood needed was kept.) The article continues with a demonstration that "Robin Hood's barn" can be replaced by any place that was a long way away from the intended end point. This supports Spagirl's comment above.

The article continues:

> Here's a colorful phrase known only to folks around Raleigh County in southern West Virginia: "I had to go all the way to Egery and back to get that." "Egery" referring to Egeria, a little community WAY out in the country close to Flat Top, West Virginia.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that it matters whose barn, or, when you go around it.  There is the phrase, "Go around the barn."

https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/go%20around%20the%20barn

Specifically, "Valeriy 2010-01-12 09:02:40
I have found some comments abt "all around Robin Hood's barn" @ phrases.org.uk:
"Robin Hood (or 'Robert of the wood,' as some have explained the name) may have been altogether a legendary figure or may have actually existed. No one knows. The earliest literary reference to him is in Langland's 'Piers Plowman,' written about 1377. He may have lived, according to some light evidence, toward the latter part of the twelfth century. But Robin Hood's house was Sherwood Forest; its roof the leaves and branches. His dinner was the king's deer; his wealth the purses of hapless travelers. What need had he of a barn, and how was it laid out if to go around it means, as the use of the phrase implies, a rambling roundabout course?

The explanation is simple. He had no barn. His granary, when he had need of one, was the cornfields of the neighborhood. To go around his barn was to make a circuitous route around the neighborhood fields." From "A Hog on Ice" (1948, Harper & Row) by Charles Earle Funk. This is one in a series of four books by Mr. Funk now available in one volume.

Here's a colorful phrase known only to folks around Raleigh County in southern West Virginia: "I had to go all the way to Egery and back to get that." "Egery" referring to Egeria, a little community WAY out in the country close to Flat Top, West Virginia."

http://www.english-slang.com/eng/more_expressions/go-around-the-barn-at-high-noon

Answer (score 1):

Your daughter seems to be correct.  I have never heard the expression myself.  Hiram's or Robin Hood's barn.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/around-robin-hood-s-barn